# Android Navigation component: IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, navigation, components, android-architecture-navigation

Navigation component crashes when i used in Rrecyclerview adapter .
First click work good but second time i click App will be crash.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            try {

                NewsList newsListData = newsLists.get(position);

                if (newsListData != null) {
                    holder.title.setText(newsListData.getNewsTitle());
                    holder.id.setText(newsListData.getNewsID());
                    holder.description.setText(newsListData.getNewsDescription());
                    holder.itemCick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                            bundle.putString("newsID", "01");
                            Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_detailsFragments,bundle);

                        }
                    });
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

> Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: navigation destination
>   app.jobs:id/action_homeFragment_to_detailsFragments is unknown to this
>   NavController.

```
**Navigation Graph:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/home_view"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/detailsFragments"
        android:name="app.jobs.Fragments.DetailsFragments"
        android:label="fragment_details_fragments"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_details_fragments">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_detailsFragments_to_homeFragment"
            app:destination="@id/homeFragment" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="app.jobs.Fragments.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_homeFragment_to_detailsFragments"
            app:destination="@id/detailsFragments"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/slide_in_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/slide_out_left"
            app:launchSingleTop="false"
            app:popEnterAnim="@anim/slide_in_left"
            app:popExitAnim="@anim/slide_out_right"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/homeFragment" />
        <argument
            android:name="newsMain"
            app:argType="string"
            android:defaultValue="newsID" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

Please help provide solution for this.

Comment: Navigation.findNavController(v) method declaration ?

Comment: try global action.

Comment: I already used global action :Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_detailsFragments,bundle); @HussnainHaidar

Comment: That's not global action. read [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-global-action) about.

Comment: Ok  i try and it's working . But question is that in every recyclerview adapter click require global action to navigate next fragment ? @HussnainHaidar

Comment: No, there's maybe another better solution for that but i don't know yet. I'm also stuck with same problem in pager adapter and i solved the problem with global action.